# How to specify url-rewritting in tomcat 6 always even though browser supports URLRewriting concept

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I want to use URLRewriting concept in my project by using Tomcat 6 server. But when the browser supports cookies then container will ignore URLRewriting concept. So How do I explicitly mention to the Tomcat 6 server to use URLRewrting concept always even though the browser supports the cookies.

Comment: Please use a readable phrase as your question title. This one I can't parse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the **/META-INF/context.xml** inside the application files, and set one of the [context attribute](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) *cookies=false*.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="PATH_TO_WEBAPP" path="/CONTEXT" cookies="false">
</Context>
```

But then , you need to explicitly use `java.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` methods `encodeURL(String url)` and `encodeRedirectURL(String URL)` to encode SessionID on URL to support URL-rewriting.